# npm build:aot --prod Duplicate source map file for dist/main-xxx.css

Tags: angular, npm, angular6, webpack-4

I'm using webpack and Angular 6. Since yesterday and without apparent changes in css files, I did not compile the npm run build: aot: prod for a problem in the creation of main-xxx.css, the bugsnag informs me that it is trying to rewrite a file that already exists and does not complete the build successfully.

It's funny that on the server deploy if it compiles correctly, but on my computer it does not, I get the following error:
Conflict (409) - duplicate source map file for dist / main-f751fc480956a7a013da.css. There was a moment this morning when he did complete the build but most times not. I found a solution to configure the override: true in BugsnagSourceMapUploaderPlugin, but I do not like it since before this error had never been reproduced.

It seems that it tries to compile the css (created with sass) twice.

If someone encountered the same problem or knows how to debug to find the fault, it will help me a lot.
Thank you very much in advance.

This is my webpack-prod configuration

```html
/**
 * @author: @AngularClass
 */
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const buildUtils = require('./build-utils');

/**
 * Used to merge webpack configs
 */
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
/**
 * The settings that are common to prod and dev
 */
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

/**
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
const SourceMapDevToolPlugin = require('webpack/lib/SourceMapDevToolPlugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HashedModuleIdsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/HashedModuleIdsPlugin');
const PurifyPlugin = require('@angular-devkit/build-optimizer').PurifyPlugin;
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const {BugsnagSourceMapUploaderPlugin} = require('webpack-bugsnag-plugins');

function getUglifyOptions(supportES2015) {
  const uglifyCompressOptions = {
    pure_getters: true, /* buildOptimizer */
    // PURE comments work best with 3 passes.
    // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2899#issuecomment-317425926.
    passes: 3         /* buildOptimizer */
  };

  return {
    ecma: supportES2015 ? 6 : 5,
    warnings: false,    // TODO verbose based on option?
    ie8: false,
    mangle: true,
    compress: uglifyCompressOptions,
    output: {
      ascii_only: true,
      comments: false
    }
  };
}

module.exports = function (env) {
  const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';
  const supportES2015 = buildUtils.supportES2015(buildUtils.DEFAULT_METADATA.tsConfigPath);
  const METADATA = Object.assign({}, buildUtils.DEFAULT_METADATA, {
    host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
    port: process.env.PORT || 8080,
    ENV: ENV,
    HMR: false
  });

  // set environment suffix so these environments are loaded.
  //METADATA.envFileSuffix = METADATA.E2E ? 'e2e.prod' : 'prod';
  METADATA.envFileSuffix = METADATA.envFileSuffix || 'pre';

  return webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV, metadata: METADATA}), {

    /**
     * Options affecting the output of the compilation.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output
     */
    output: {

      /**
       * The output directory as absolute path (required).
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-path
       */
      path: helpers.root('dist'),
      /**
       * Specifies the name of each output file on disk.
       * IMPORTANT: You must not specify an absolute path here!
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-filename
       */
      filename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js',

      /**
       * The filename of the SourceMaps for the JavaScript files.
       * They are inside the output.path directory.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-sourcemapfilename
       */
      sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',

      /**
       * The filename of non-entry chunks as relative path
       * inside the output.path directory.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-chunkfilename
       */
      chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js'
    },

    module: {

      rules: [
        /**
         * Extract CSS files from .src/styles directory to external CSS file
         */
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
          include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },

        /**
         * Extract and compile SCSS files from .src/styles directory to external CSS file
         */
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        }
      ]
    },

    /**
     * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
     */
    plugins: [

      new SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        filename: '[file].map[query]',
        moduleFilenameTemplate: '[resource-path]',
        fallbackModuleFilenameTemplate: '[resource-path]?[hash]',
        sourceRoot: 'webpack:///'
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '[name]-[hash].css', chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].css' }),
      new PurifyPlugin(), /* buildOptimizer */
      new HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
      /**
       * Plugin: UglifyJsPlugin
       * Description: Minimize all JavaScript output of chunks.
       * Loaders are switched into minimizing mode.
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin
       *
       * NOTE: To debug prod builds uncomment //debug lines and comment //prod lines
       */
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: false,
        parallel: true,
        uglifyOptions: getUglifyOptions(supportES2015)
      }),
      new BugsnagSourceMapUploaderPlugin({
        apiKey: METADATA.bugsnagKey,
        publicPath: 'dist'
      })

    ],

    /**
     * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
     * Description: Node configuration
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
     */
    node: {
      global: true,
      crypto: 'empty',
      process: false,
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Try to build without source maps, on angular cli its done with --source-map=false

Comment: Finally after long days, I found that the error was caused by the bugSnag since the file existed, it is not a problem of webpack or of the build. Activating the overwrite: true option in the BugsnagSourceMapUploaderPlugin or removing the sourMap was fixed. What I do not understand is how the build does not compile for that kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Xavier is right. I had the same issue. It was under webpack.prod.js file. By default overwrite is not enabled. I searched with appVersion in the project.

```
new BugsnagSourceMapUploaderPlugin({
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  appVersion: '4.0.0.038',
  overwrite: true
})
```

Details can be found [here](https://github.com/bugsnag/webpack-bugsnag-plugins/issues/15) in the BugSnag GitHub page.